# Stored procedure throwing error on execution, I don't see the incorrect syntax where the error says

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure that I have written and when I go to execute it I keep getting an error...

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure s_Add$Subject$Info, Line 127
>   Incorrect syntax near '@V'.

When I go to line 127 and look around, I can't see any incorrect syntax at the line or even in the area of it. Is there something I am not seeing? here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE s_Add$Subject$Info
(
   @SubjectName varchar(50),
   @SubjectDescription varchar(max),
   @QuizIDString varchar(100),
   @GamesIDString varchar(100),
   @VideoIDString varchar(100)
)
as
--declare variables
declare @theSubID int
declare @quizIDLength int
declare @gamesIDLength int
declare @videoIDLength int
declare @quizIDs varchar(200)
declare @gamesIDs varchar(200)
declare @videoIDs varchar(200)
declare @numberCount int
declare @sTemp varchar(100)

--initializing variables
set @quizIDLength = LEN(@QuizIDString)
set @gamesIDLength = LEN(@GamesIDString)
set @videoIDLength = LEN(@VideoIDString)
set @quizIDs = ''
set @gamesIDs = ''
set @videoIDs = ''
set @numberCount = 1


--declare temp tables
declare @Q table --Quiz 
(
QuizID varchar(100),
SubjectID int
)

declare @G table --Games
(
GamesID varchar(100),
SubjectID int
)

declare @V table --Videos
(
VideoID varchar(100),
SubjectID int
)

insert into[Subjects]
(SubjectName, SubjectDescription)
values
(@SubjectName, @SubjectDescription)
set @TheSubID = @@IDENTITY

--Check to see what strings are full then entering ids if true
--Quizzes first
if(@QuizIDLength > 0)
begin
    while(@numberCount <=@quizIDLength)
begin
    set @sTemp = SUBSTRING(@QuizIDString, @numberCount, 1)
if(@sTemp = ',')
begin 
    insert @Q (QuizID, SubjectID) values (@quizIDs, @theSubID)
    set @quizIDs = ''
end
if(@sTemp <> ',')
begin
    set @quizIDs = @quizIDs + @sTemp
end
    set @numberCount = @numberCount + 1
end
--Games second
if(@gamesIDLength > 0)
begin
    while(@numberCount <=@gamesIDLength)
begin
    set @sTemp = SUBSTRING(@GamesIDString, @numberCount, 1)
if(@sTemp = ',')
begin 
    insert @G (GamesID, SubjectID) values (@gamesIDs, @theSubID)
    set @gamesIDs = ''
end
if(@sTemp <> ',')
begin
    set @gamesIDs = @gamesIDs + @sTemp
end
    set @numberCount = @numberCount + 1
end

--Videos third
if(@videoIDLength > 0)
begin
    while(@numberCount <=@videoIDLength)
begin
    set @sTemp = SUBSTRING(@VideoIDString, @numberCount, 1)
if(@sTemp = ',')
begin 
    insert @V (VideoID, SubjectID) values (@videoIDs, @theSubID)
    set @videoIDs = ''
end
if(@sTemp <> ',')
begin
    set @videoIDs = @videoIDs + @sTemp
end
    set @numberCount = @numberCount + 1
end

--inserting the ids to subjectinfo table
insert into [SubjectInfo]
(SubjectID, QuizID)
select SubjectID, QuizID
from @Q

--Games
insert into [SubjectInfo]
(SubjectID, GameID)
select SubjectID, GameID
from @G

--Video
insert into [SubjectInfo]
(SubjectID, VideoID)
select SubjectID, VideoID
from @V
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you used better indentation formatting you'd easily be able to see that the problem is that you are missing some `END` statements:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE s_Add$Subject$Info
(
    @SubjectName varchar(50),
    @SubjectDescription varchar(max),
    @QuizIDString varchar(100),
    @GamesIDString varchar(100),
    @VideoIDString varchar(100)
)
as

--declare variables
declare @theSubID int
declare @quizIDLength int
declare @gamesIDLength int
declare @videoIDLength int
declare @quizIDs varchar(200)
declare @gamesIDs varchar(200)
declare @videoIDs varchar(200)
declare @numberCount int
declare @sTemp varchar(100)

--initializing variables
set @quizIDLength = LEN(@QuizIDString)
set @gamesIDLength = LEN(@GamesIDString)
set @videoIDLength = LEN(@VideoIDString)
set @quizIDs = ''
set @gamesIDs = ''
set @videoIDs = ''
set @numberCount = 1


--declare temp tables
declare @Q table --Quiz 
(
    QuizID varchar(100),
    SubjectID int
)

declare @G table --Games
(
    GamesID varchar(100),
    SubjectID int
)

declare @V table --Videos
(
    VideoID varchar(100),
    SubjectID int
)

insert into[Subjects]
    (SubjectName, SubjectDescription)
values
    (@SubjectName, @SubjectDescription)
set @TheSubID = @@IDENTITY

--Check to see what strings are full then entering ids if true
--Quizzes first
if(@QuizIDLength > 0)
begin
    while(@numberCount <=@quizIDLength)
    begin
        set @sTemp = SUBSTRING(@QuizIDString, @numberCount, 1)
        if(@sTemp = ',')
        begin 
            insert @Q (QuizID, SubjectID) values (@quizIDs, @theSubID)
            set @quizIDs = ''
        end
        if(@sTemp <> ',')
        begin
            set @quizIDs = @quizIDs + @sTemp
        end
        set @numberCount = @numberCount + 1
    end
    --Games second
    if(@gamesIDLength > 0)
    begin
        while(@numberCount <=@gamesIDLength)
        begin
            set @sTemp = SUBSTRING(@GamesIDString, @numberCount, 1)
            if(@sTemp = ',')
            begin 
                insert @G (GamesID, SubjectID) values (@gamesIDs, @theSubID)
                set @gamesIDs = ''
            end
            if(@sTemp <> ',')
            begin
                set @gamesIDs = @gamesIDs + @sTemp
            end
            set @numberCount = @numberCount + 1
        end

        --Videos third
        if(@videoIDLength > 0)
        begin
            while(@numberCount <=@videoIDLength)
            begin
                set @sTemp = SUBSTRING(@VideoIDString, @numberCount, 1)
                if(@sTemp = ',')
                begin 
                    insert @V (VideoID, SubjectID) values (@videoIDs, @theSubID)
                    set @videoIDs = ''
                end
                if(@sTemp <> ',')
                begin
                    set @videoIDs = @videoIDs + @sTemp
                end
                set @numberCount = @numberCount + 1
            end

        --inserting the ids to subjectinfo table
        insert into [SubjectInfo]
            (SubjectID, QuizID)
        select SubjectID, QuizID
        from @Q

        --Games
        insert into [SubjectInfo]
            (SubjectID, GameID)
        select SubjectID, GameID
        from @G

        --Video
        insert into [SubjectInfo]
            (SubjectID, VideoID)
        select SubjectID, VideoID
        from @V
```

Comment: After relooking over your formatted version I see exactly what you are saying and have added the missing end statements and its executing like a charm. Thanks for the help, if I had properly formatted it then I would have seen it too :)

Comment: @user2970223 And things like that are actually the purpose of such formatting.

Comment: and that every BEGIN statement needs a corresponding END

Answer (score 3):

You missed the `into` keyword

```
insert   @V (VideoID, SubjectID) values (@videoIDs, @theSubID)
       ^-------here
```

Comment: While true, that's not the problem being reported at line 127.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure that the `INTO` is optional ... ?

Comment: Yep. [`INSERT  [ INTO ]`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) in the grammar.

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing out the missing INTO, I glossed over that.